# WCF: Significant Lag Returning Large Data Set over HttpBinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, soa

I have a WCF service using Entity Framework 6 hosted in a simple Windows Forms app. My WPF client app requests a large view (11000 records) from the service which is added to an ObservableCOllection. The client machine is connected to our VPN over WiFi.

When I run SQL Server Profiler on the db I can see that the query itself is very fast however, the `Audit Logout` duration is long, suggesting that the connection is staying open for a long time as WCF returns the data to the client over Http:

[image]

When on my networked Dev machine, this transaction is very fast. If I reduce the query results (e.g. SELECT TOP 200...) the process speeds up considerably therefore I know it is the sheer volume of data causing the issue.

Here is my current binding:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://emea-diis01v:8082/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" contract="ServiceReference.IIsesService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" />
    </client>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have tried implemented Mtom messaging but this had no noticeable positive effect. I have read around using GZip compression with a custom binding. Is this the best course of action? the implementation documentation is very thin.

Failing that, is it likely that Net TCP binding could prove more efficient and if so how is this implemented when hosting a WCF service in a Winforms app rather than with IIS?

Unfortunately, the user requirements dictate that the whole view is returned to the client UI, I cannot page or async the results.

Comment: Think about the problem for a bit first. WHY ON EARTH DO YOU WANT TO PULL DOWN 11000 records? Ahem...Does facebook pull down 10 years worth of wall/feed in one go, hey that uses GZip compression. By the way, you don't even need to use customBinding to use GZip. You can use IIS dynamic compression instead, for better performance.

Comment: This is an article editing tool. The user needs all of the data presented to them in a dataGrid. This isn't Facebook, the requirements are completely different...

Comment: You might try to stream the response. Have a look at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The only "solution" would be to download the data in smaller, more efficient batches and then concatenate the results (i.e. multiple calls to your service), but the end result will still be rather slow. The requirement is simply ridiculous: no sane person will sit down to edit **eleven thousand** items in one go. Moreover: the same issue will be there when you upload the data.

Comment: No I see your point re the number of records. The user edits articles from all over the world. The articles are defined by country. Therefore I can't serve up say TOP 200 as then the user will only receive 'Afghanistan' articles. They need to be able to scroll to their country of interest & at least have the illusion that all the data is there, even if it's not...

Comment: I've tried to stream the response, didn't make any difference. I have filters in the UI so the user can select by country etc which adds a where clause vastly reducing the no of returned records. Think I'm going to have to rethink the UI somehow. This is an established application  which I'm re-architecting to SOA to allow remote use.

Comment: Are you returning *all* of the data for each article? Why not a more hierarchical approach - say, list of article titles and other metadata, and then only retrieve the full data for a particular article when they request it?

Comment: Also, WCF allows you to define on-the-wire serialization that will be more efficient than the XML you're probably using right now.

Comment: @GalaticCowboy, yes unfortunately I need the article bodies which are by far the biggest chunk in the request. The user can browse the articles by body & make a selection from hereonin

Answer (score 1):

I have serious concerns over the statement

> I have a WCF service using Entity Framework 6 hosted in a simple
>   Windows Forms app

This paints a very confused picture to me. It suggests that you have a "master" WPF app with the service in it, and then you distribute a bunch of WPF client apps which have the WCF client in them? The config sample you have provided defines a service client, not a service host. There are many reasons why a WPF app is a very unsuitable host for a wcf service.

> The user edits articles from all over the world. The articles are
>   defined by country. Therefore I can't serve up say TOP 200 as then the
>   user will only receive 'Afghanistan' articles. They need to be able to scroll 
>   to their country of interest

This is the key to addressing your problem. The data can be effectively *sharded* (or even exposed using views) into smaller sets of data, maybe by country and date as an example.

> Failing that, is it likely that Net TCP binding could prove more
>   efficient and if so how is this implemented when hosting a WCF service
>   in a Winforms app rather than with IIS?

Yes! netTcpBinding is [much faster](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684.chart(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg) than http. That would certainly speed stuff up. You can use it over the internet but be aware that firewalls block TCP traffic on unopenned ports.

The wcf hosting container being WPF doesn't limit you to choice of transport bindings, but remains a very unorthodox choice.

Comment: The WCF service is hosted by a Windows Forms app. The client app consuming the service is WPF. The config I posted is from the Service app.config. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: My point still holds - winforms is if anything more unorthodox than WPF. So are you saying that the service only exists if the windows form app is running?

Comment: The service is hosted by a winforms app so yes. There's a start button which invokes  host = new ServiceHost(typeof(IsesService.IsesService));
            host.Open();. This is a common way to host a WCF service without using IIS...

Comment: So what happens if a client calls the service and the winforms app happens to be closed? And I can very much assure you it's **not** a common way to host WCF services. Just look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - winforms/wpf conspicuously absent

Comment: Yes, the article you linked. read the Self-Hosting in a Managed Application section... That's exactly what I'm doing. If the service isn't running the client UI throws a message box conveying the issue. I've started my journey into WCF via PluralSight's 'WCF Jumpstart' course which specifically details this very process.

Comment: You should host your app in a Windows service or in a Web app in IIS. Those are the only solid options.

Comment: @Hardgraf - you're right - in that article it does outline your exact use-case. I must say I'm surprised, but I guess I've just not come across that kind of thing before.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run SQL Server Profiler on the db I can see that the query itself is very fast

You have you used a SQL profiler, but you haven't provided any profiling information related to your WCF service, EF etc. which is much more important for troubleshooting this.

Assuming your message size is 4KB, that would mean you are transferring dozens of MB over the wire at once, and in addition using buffering on both ends, which is not optimal for big payloads. Default XML Serialization/Deserialization of those records is a problem too, because its slow. Pulling 11K using an ORM like EF is also not a good idea, because its slower than ADO.NET or MicroORMs. So your whole architecture is wrong.

> I've tried to stream the response, didn't make any difference.

Streaming is more efficient for big messages than Buffering, but it must be implemented correctly on the server, and especially on the client to have an effect. If you use streams the wrong way, they could be slower than buffering.

However, optimizing the current implementation is not the right approach, your actual problem is the assumption you need 11K records upfront on the UI. You should re-think your UI architecture and pull data on demand.

> Unfortunately, the user requirements dictate that the whole view is returned to the client UI, I cannot page or async the results.

One of the techniques you could use is **infinite scrolling**. There are many more.

In addition, you should use Async IO whenever you are dealing with remote services, unless you want to kill the scalability of your app.

Comment: I'm using EF6 .edmx model in my WCF service solution. I'm hitting the SQL server database using Linq to Entities (eg. var query = from a in _Context.Articles select a;). The results are returned to an ObservableCollection on the client side. ObservableCollection<Articles> = new ObservableCollection<Articles>(ServiceInstance.GetAllArticles());

Comment: Do a microbenchmark and measure the response time of that query in C#. And then refactor it to use a MicroORM like dapper or raw ADO.NET and see the difference. If you want performance never use big, bloated ORMs.

Comment: I can watch the query on the profiler, the query executes very quickly. I think it's a combination of Entity Framework & the sheer size of the result set over a bottle necked vpn which is slowing things down. Maybe native SQL would be quicker, but like you've pointed out, really the UI needs to be filtered on initialisation as to not return 11000 records.

Comment: Yeah the query is fast, but EF adds much more stuff on top of the query. There is a price for abstraction. You can improve stuff on all layers and get a really fast app. You should definitely filter, paginate or infinite scroll with pulling smaller chunks of data ;)

Comment: Yes. Raw SQL might improve things but not so drastically as to turn 30 seconds latency time into an instant response. The issue lies in attempting to pull 11000 records which contain sizable text article bodys from the db in one go.

Comment: Exactly. I wasn't saying EF is the only issue, but it could improve performance a little bit to use more performant ADO.NET. You are right the real problem is the size of the payload and how it's transferred over the wire and handled on the client.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I ended up bringing in the last month's worth of data into the ObservableCollection. The user can then filter further into the data if they want to view older articles.